# Problems with Cyrillic symbols

Tags: php, character-encoding, multibyte

The following code doesn't detect encoding correct.

```
$data = 'ABCDEG АБВГДЕ';
$charset = mb_detect_encoding($data);
$data = iconv($charset, "UTF-8", $data);
$data = mb_strtolower($data, 'UTF-8');
$datasort = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", " "), '', $data);
$counter = mb_strlen($datasort,'UTF-8');
foreach (count_chars($datasort, 1) as $i => $val) 
{
echo '
<tr>
    <th scope="row">'.mb_detect_encoding(chr($i)).'</th>
// ON LATIN SYMBOLS IT DETECTED ANCII AND ON CYRILLIC IT DETECTED **NOTHING**
</tr>
';
}
```

Where here could be the problem?
//php file have UTF-8 encoding

Comment: ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so if a document is ASCII then it is already UTF-8. In this case all letters will return ASCII but if you did to the word before looping and try to detect encoding it will give you UTF-8

Comment: @headmax Thats right. But primary question is: why when I try to detected encoding of cyrillic, I get **nothing** instead ASCII

Comment: Why would you want to detect (guess) a character encoding? You simply have to read with the encoding the text was written with. Have you lost that essential information (metadata)? In this case, the encoding is the one you told your editor to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and all that will be ASCII Or UTF-8 : the problem with your code is that **count_chars change the encoding during the convert...**

```
function mbStringToArray ($string) {
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array;
} 

$data = 'ABCDEG АБВГДЕ';
$data = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", " "), '', mb_strtolower($data));
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($data, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $data);

$data = mbStringToArray($data);

echo '<table>';
foreach ($data as $i => $val) 
{
echo '
<tr>
    <th scope="row">'. $val . ' : ' .mb_detect_encoding(chr($i)).'</th>
</tr>
';
}
echo '</table>';
```

> A : ASCII 
>   B : UTF-8 
>   C : UTF-8 
>   D : UTF-8 
>   E : UTF-8 
>   G : UTF-8 
>   А : UTF-8
>   Б : UTF-8 
>   В : UTF-8 
>   Г : ASCII 
>   Д : ASCII 
>   Е : UTF-8